# How to handle pressing C+/ keys on JS(key combination) and invoke some function?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts

```
const cKeycode = 67; 
const SlashKeyCode = 191; 
document.onkeyup = function(e){  
 var e = e || window.event;   
 if(e.keyCode==cKeycode && e.which == SlashKeyCode) {
   alert("C+/ pressed");
   return false;   
  }
}
```

I've just tried this one and many other variants but I can't handle this. Maybe someone know the better way

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because the event only passes one key at a time (excluding keys like ctrl and alt). To get around this, we can store if either key is pressed, then check this once the second key is pressed. **This method works whether the user presses `c` *then* `/`, or if they press `/` *then* `c`.**

```js
const keys = ["c", "/"];
var pressedKey = -1;
document.onkeydown = function(e){  
 var e = e || window.event;
 let key = e.key;
 if (keys.indexOf(key) > -1) {
  if (pressedKey === -1) pressedKey = key;
  else if (pressedKey !== key) console.log("C + / pressed");
 }
}

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  let key = e.key;
  if (key === pressedKey) pressedKey = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **onkeyup** event doesn't return a collection of pressed keys - it just returns a single key at a time. Furthermore onkeyup just fires if you actually release a key so if you want to know when two keys are pressed you need to utilize the **onkeydown** event.

To do this create a global boolean variable which states if the first button is actually pressed and if it is, check if the second key is pressed as well.

Here's an example. For simplicity I'm using the a and e key.

```js
const AKeycode = 65;
const EKeycode = 69;
let AKeycodeDown = false;
let EKeycodeDown = false;
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == AKeycode) {
    AKeycodeDown = true;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == EKeycode) {
    EKeycodeDown = true;
  }
  if (AKeycodeDown && e.keyCode == EKeycode || EKeycodeDown && e.keyCode == AKeycode) {
    AKeycodeDown = false;
    EKeycodeDown = false;
    alert("A+E pressed");
  }
}

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == AKeycode) {
    AKeycodeDown = false;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == EKeycode) {
    EKeycodeDown = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly. If the user presses `e` *then* `a`, it doesn't alert. Also, if the user lets go, then presses **only** `e`, it calls the alert.